# can we call a overridden method of super class from subclass object that is in another class

Tags: java, oop, overriding

```
class A{
    int i,j;
    A(int x,int y){
        i=x;j=y;
    }
    void show(){
        System.out.println("i="+i+" j="+j);
    }
}

class B extends A{    
    int k;
    B(int i,int j,int k){
        super(i,j);
        this.k=k;
    }
    void show(){
        System.out.println("k="+k);
    }
}

public class overridingEx{
    B ob=new B(1,2,3);
    ob.show();    // this will call the B's show method.
}
```

Please tell me is there a way to call A class method from B's class object ob ?

Comment: Inside B's `show()`, by calling `super.show()`.

Comment: sorry I am new to stack overflow so please forgive me for not using code editor effeciently. :(

Comment: You can use `super` but I am just queries to know if B has overriden then what is the need for calling method from A.

Comment: @SachinThapa "curious" :P

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Ha ha what a catch.. i am writing too many queries :-D

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `A`'s `show` method from `ob`.  You should call `super.show()` from within `B`'s `show` method.

```
void show(){
    super.show();
    System.out.println("k="+k);
}
```

Now, when `ob.show()` is called, you'll see output from both `show()` methods:

```
i=1 j=2
k=3
```

Calling `super.show()` from within a subclass calls the superclass's implementation of the `show()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `super` to explcitly use the superclass's methods, constants, constructors, etc.

Put `super.show()` into `B` and it will use `A#show()`.